# Oracle select with sub queries

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two oracle select queries like

```
SELECT loc.location AS LOCATION , req.requisition AS REQ 
FROM location_view loc, requisition_view req, association ass 
WHERE loc.name = 'ABC' AND req.name = 'TRANSFER' 
AND ass.entity_id_2 = req.entity_id AND ass.entity_id_1 = loc.entity_id
```

And the **result** looks like:

[image]

Other query is like:

```
 SELECT req.requisition AS req, exp.experiment AS expt 
 FROM experiment_view exp, requisition_view req, association_view ass 
 WHERE expt.name = 'RETRIEVAL'AND req.name = 'TRANSFER' 
 AND ass.entity_id_2 = req.entity_id AND ass.entity_id_1 = expt.entity_id
```

**Result**:

[image]

I am trying to combine these two `SELECT` queries so I get to see these results:

[image]

Should I be using Sub-Queries to see the combined result or is there any other way of optimizing?

Comment: This makes no sense. Besides obvious typos (so these are NOT the queries that produce the results you show, since they are syntactically incorrect), how does it make sense for `ass.entity_id_1` to be used to match both the `location_view` view and the `experiment_view` view?

Comment: What syntax errors did you find? Looked valid, if a little ancient, to me!

Comment: @mathguy : Well it makes sense given that it's not the same row. There is one row in locations, 1 in requisitions, 1 in experiments and 2 in associations. The first row in associations links the loc to the req and the second row links the rep to the exp. I personally hate these multipurpose generic association tables but people keep doing them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the provided solutions are correct. All of them are using 1 join to the association table. You need 2. Because Association looks to be a generic mapping table so the row that joins locations to requisitions is not the same as the one which joins requisitions to experiments. Maybe i'm wrong but i'd go for :

```
SELECT
  loc.location as LOCATION , 
  req.requisition as REQ, 
  exp.experiment as EXPT
FROM  location_view    loc
JOIN  association      asslr ON asslr.entity_id_1 = loc.entity_id
JOIN  requisition_view req   ON asslr.entity_id_2 = req.entity_id and req.name = 'TRANSFER'
JOIN  association_view assre ON assre.entity_id_2 = req.entity_id
JOIN  experiment_view  exp   ON assre.entity_id_1 = exp.entity_id AND exp.name = 'RETRIEVAL'
WHERE loc.name = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Good catch, very subtle that difference you spotted. Well doen

Answer (score 0):

The two queries are nearly identical. The results can be joined together on a common element so yes, they can just be written as one query:

```
select loc.location as LOCATION , req.requisition as REQ, exp.experiment as expt
from location_view loc, requisition_view req, association ass, experiment_view exp
where  loc.name = 'ABC' and req.name = 'TRANSFER' and ass.entity_id_2 = req.entity_id and ass.entity_id_1 = loc.entity_id and ass.entity_id_1 = expt.entity_id and expt.name = 'RETRIEVAL'
```

This is a bit of an ancient nonstandard way to write queries though; look into how the INNER JOIN keywords work; here's how I'd have laid this query out:

```
select
  loc.location as LOCATION , 
  req.requisition as REQ, 
  exp.experiment as expt
from 
  association ass
  INNER JOIN
  location_view loc
  ON
    ass.entity_id_1 = loc.entity_id

  INNER JOIN 
  requisition_view req 
  on 
    ass.entity_id_2 = req.entity_id

  INNER JOIN
  experiment_view expt
  ON
    ass.entity_id_1 = expt.entity_id

WHERE        
  loc.name = 'ABC' and
  req.name = 'TRANSFER' and
  expt.name = 'RETRIEVAL'
```

Comment: I tried the first statement with out using joins but it is not returning any records

Comment: @trx Try laudec's answer; he notices that one of your query uses association table, other uses association_view table. I didn't notice this and it could be a critical difference.. another good reason why you should lay your sql out nicely; makes them easier to read!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT loc.location AS location, 
       req.requisition AS req,
       exp.experiment AS expt
  FROM location_view loc
 INNER JOIN association ass
    ON loc.entity_id = ass.entity_id_1
 INNER JOIN requisition_view req
    ON req.entity_id = ass.entity_id_2
 INNER JOIN experiment_view exp
    ON expt.entity_id = ass.entity_id_1
 WHERE loc.name = 'ABC'
   AND req.name = 'TRANSFER' 
   AND expt.name = 'RETRIEVAL'
```